# Why is this translation animation not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-animation

I have the following animation that on some event should cause a button to move from left to right:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="{Binding StudioOpacityValue}" Duration="0:0:2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To="500"  Duration="0:0:2">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Name="mainGrid" >

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="FadeInMainButtonsAfterImport" SourceObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
            <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Button x:Name ="Studio" Grid.Row="33" Grid.Column="57" Grid.ColumnSpan="36" Grid.RowSpan="36"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsStudioEnabled}" Opacity="{Binding StudioOpacityValue}" >
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>

<Grid>
```

but nothing happens. What may be the problem?

Comment: `FadeInMainButtonsAfterImport` what is this event?

Comment: that is the event that should trigger this animation and it works. I know that because on this event, the same button fades in, but does not want to translate.

Comment: try accessing the targetproperty like this: `(UIElement.RenderTransform).Children[0].(TranslateTransform.X)`

Comment: I get runtime error:  "Cannot resolve all property references in the property path '(0).Children[0].(1)'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties."

Comment: I indented your code and added a `</i:Interaction.Triggers>` near the end. May that have been the problem?

Comment: @zx485 a button cannot be a part of interaction triggers :D

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic that is not correct.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic: That may be, but the XML was not well-formed. XAML is XML and therefore must be well-formed to be effective. I ran my edit through an XML parser and it it correct.

Comment: @zx485 never add anything to someones answer, how do you expect people to trouble shoot effectively that way for them? Fix nuances like spelling, grammar, indentation, fine... but never add anything.

Comment: @ChrisW. What i meant to say was that you can't put a Button inside <i:Interaction.Triggers></i:Interaction.Triggers> tag

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic OH! I'm sorry I completely misinterpreted then! In that case then yes you're absolutely correct!

Comment: @Chris W.: I had a similar discussion yesterday. I do not _change_ the question. I rather purify it from any (c/p) errors for others to have an easier going on approaching its solution. I learnt from yesterdays experience that I should notify the community of doing that. I did. Now I _do_ mention the changes I did to the question explicitly in the comments.

Comment: @zx485 very understandable. However what if the case was what you added was actually the answer to their dilemma? Sorry man I'm not a mod or anything but I generally just take it as a rule of thumb. Though may be worth asking over on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, but we need to tweak a couple things.

Open up the property on your button so it know's what we're dealing with. Right now you're targeting the object, not the transform. So we do something like;

```
<Button x:Name="Studio" 
        Grid.Row="33" Grid.Column="57" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="36" Grid.RowSpan="36" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsStudioEnabled}" 
        Opacity="{Binding StudioOpacityValue}" >
   <Button.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform x:Name="StudioTranslate" X="0"/>
   </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

You're close with the DoubleAnimation, but there's key frames in between for that animation to occur so handle those pesky spline interpolation like;

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StudioTranslate" 
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:2">
   <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="500" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

This is generally how I do it anyway. Hope it helps, cheers.

**ADDENDUM:**

To associate easing functions to a DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames we flip from spline to [EasingDoubleKeyFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.easingdoublekeyframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StudioTranslate" 
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:2">
   <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="500">
      <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
         <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
      </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
   </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The only problem is that I can not apply the easing function like I did with standard double animation:  <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction> How would you solve this?

Comment: @Ivan I'm sorry, I forgot all about the easing! See updated answer, we just flip from spline to easing. Let me know if you run into issues. Cheers!

Comment: Don't forget to change KeyTime from `0:0:0` to `0:0:2`, the animation won't work otherwise :)

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic Haha I have to stop doing this stuff freehand without testing...it's a horrible habit I have. :/

Comment: @ChrisW. You wrote all of this without testing? Whoa, that's amazing. I usually can't remember anything without some form of IDE to help me :D

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try it tomorrow. Just one more thing...is the 'Value' property bindable? i tried to bind it to the actual with of some other wpf control, but it didn't work. If i use fixed value of 500 then it works

Comment: @Ivan if you're not storing this animation in a style or datatemplate/controltemplate than it is bindable

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic eh, it's like anything else if you do it enough times, but obviously there's going to be instances where anyone can be humbled lol.

Comment: @Ivan I would assume it's bindable, maybe show how you're trying to bind? It may be a freezable but I don't believe so, I'd have to double check to be sure.

Comment: @Chris W. I tried to bind it to some other control's width like this: "<EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=studioStartingPoint}" KeyTime="0:0:2">" but it didn't work. I use the same binding for property 'To' of some other DoubleAnimation, and it works fine, but this particular one doesn't. What may be the problem?

Comment: @Ivan Ah ok, just checked and sure enough it's a Freezable (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.easingdoublekeyframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) but I know I've gotten around it before. If I get some free time let me dig in some old source and figure out what I did last time and I'll get back to you. :)

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot. i also found out that my original code that i posted in this question works if i use fixed value of 500. If i set 'To' property to the same binding, then it doesn't work either. But it is really funny that i have another identical DoubleAnimation in my code that works just fine with the same binding on 'To' property

Answer (score 1):

Try this (i've moved the trigger within the button) :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
               <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="{Binding StudioOpacityValue}" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To="500"  Duration="0:0:2">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>      
                    </Storyboard>
            </UserControl.Resources>

         <Grid Name="mainGrid" >

        <Button x:Name ="Studio" Grid.Row="33" Grid.Column="57" Grid.ColumnSpan="36" Grid.RowSpan="36"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsStudioEnabled}" Opacity="{Binding StudioOpacityValue}" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="FadeInMainButtonsAfterImport" SourceObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
                        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
          <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>

          </Button>

    <Grid>
```